# the list for forloop index is changing?

Tags: python

I have some easy code:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,3,3,5]
for letter in a:
  print (letter)
  if letter == 3:
     a.remove(letter)

print ('a=',a)
```

The output shows:

```
1
2
3
3
5
a= [1, 2, 4, 3, 5]
```

I expect to see:

```
1
2
3
4
3
3
5
a=[1,2,4,5]
```

What is happening? It seems in the loop that the "a" list is also being updated simultaneously. How can I fix the for loop to get the expected output?

Comment: Most pythonic way: `a = [x for x in a if x != 3]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's removing the item at index 3, not the item with the value of 3. The following list comprehension does what you want.

```
a = [letter for letter in a if letter != 3]
```

[edit] Nope, I was wrong about "remove" - I confused it with "pop"

Comment: from `help(list.remove)`: `L.remove(value) -- remove first occurrence of value.`